# Output from <= in python is weird

Tags: python, list, set

```
>>> [6,7,8,16,18] <= [6,8,11,13,17]
True
```

`<=` Should return `True` if every element in left set is in right set. But `7,16,18` are not in the right list. Even if I put the numbers in sets like so

```
>>> (6,7,8,16,18) <= (6,8,11,13,17)
True
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are using **lists and tuples**, not sets. Use [`{...}` for set literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#set-displays):

```
>>> {6, 7, 8, 16, 18} <= {6, 8, 11, 13, 17}
False
```

or use [`set([...])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) or [`frozenset([...])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-frozenset). Set literal syntax is only available in Python 2.7 and 3.x.

Lists and tuples don't support set operations. Instead, `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` comparisons follow lexicographical ordering conventions; the contents are compaired pairwise and the outcome is based on the first value that differs between the two sequences.

Lexicographically sorted, your left-hand list sorts before the right-hand (`6 == 6`, then `7 < 8`) so the outcome *for sequences* is entirely correct.